# How to get long from int

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

How to get `long` value of an `int`? For example how to get long value of -127?

Comment: Please expand the question. You can assign an int to a long. So on the face of it what you ask is trivial.

Comment: May be question is not clear, but can't you simply typecast it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about bit representation for negative numbers having a leading 1, then you could use:

```
int intValue = -127;
long longValue;
if((0x80 << (sizeof(int)-1)) & intValue)
{
    longValue = (0x80 << ((sizeof(long)-1)*8)) | ((0x80 << ((sizeof(int)-1)*8)) ^ intValue);
}else{
    longValue = intValue
}
```

I hope I did not mess up with the brackets.

Comment: This **is completely bogus**. First of all, the compiler does sign extension for you. So a simple assignment from a `signed int` to a `signed long` is all you need. Secondly, `sizeof(int)` returns a size in bytes. Shifting `0x80` to the left by a number of bytes in an int is wrong, since you want a number of bits, not bytes.

Comment: True, missed * 8, was so cought in counting brackets

Comment: The crux is not about `*8`, it's about not needing any of this code *at all*. I suggest you delete the answer, since it's very misleading and the newbies who don't know better will get utterly confused.

Comment: He did not really ask about assigning a long variable with an int value, but to get a long value out of a int variable, thats why i talked about "bit representation". If i remember correctly we had a similar problem when wrapping signed values in a predefined transport protocoll. I know you could actually just "convert" the values, but if he accepted the answer as correct, he may really was talking about bit representation. Just ask him :)

Comment: The compiler developers have already coded it up and tested it, so why reinvent the wheel? Your entire `if` statement should be replaced by `longValue = intValue`. It gives the correct bit representation. You do exactly the same thing as the assignment does, only you didn't test your version and a clever enough compiler will lower it to a sign extension *anyway*.  Your answer got accepted likely because the asker didn't know any better. If you don't want to use a long variable, just code up a function that does it. There, no explicit variable, life's good :)

Answer (score 0):

```c
int foo = -127;
long bar = foo;
assert(bar == foo); // We simply state that the values are the same
```

Or:

```c
// Decent compilers will optimize this away in release build.
long long_from_int(int x) { return x; }

int foo = -127;
assert(long_from_int(foo) == -127L);
```

That's it. Life doesn't get any easier than that :)

Answer (score -2):

Use: Long.valueOf(int)

Or if you have an 'Integer' you can also do:

Integer x = - 127;
long y = x.longValue();

Comment: What is this? Did you mean QVariant?

Comment: This is Qt (using C++), not Java